# Unable to insert values to mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, insert

I am trying to insert values to mysql using python but the code is not working, its returning a blank page & no values written in database table, Please help me

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'python', '123456', 'python');

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES('234','566789','rohan','rajesh','78979','Maths','25','50','75','P')")
cur.commit()

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Plus, is this the whole code you are running? If yes, `python` and `success` variables are not defined - so, the code doesn't work at all. Additionally, if you are using `with`, you don't need to call `close()` inside.

Comment: yes this is the whole code i am running, i am new to python , please sir can u show  me a simple example

Comment: Do you understand that each of those `INSERT` statements is creating a new row, with just one column filled in, and default values for all the other columns in that row? Is that really what you want?

Comment: What do you think you're doing with `with con:`? And what do you think is `python.commit()`? Programming isn't just throwing lines together you found somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect(host='localhost', user='python', passwd='123456', db='python');

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(ecode) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(htno) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(fathername) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(subcode) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(subject) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(internals) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(externals) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(total) VALUES('Manoj')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(result) VALUES('Manoj')")

cur.commit()

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

There were several problems:

- undefined `python` variable
- undefined `success` variable
- context managers are not supported by `MySQLdb`

Though, I don't understand why do you need to insert rows with `Manoj` value in different fields.

UPD, you have an error in your sql syntax (missing quote char before `566789`):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES('234','566789','rohan','rajesh','78979','Maths','25','50','75','P')")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please, fix your `connect` line as I've done. How do you check there is no data inserted?

Comment: The script won't show any output. Are there any data inserted? Check, please.

Comment: is there any indentation problem??

Answer (score 0):

Your Python string must be exactly as in a normal MySQL statement, so a good idea is to try executing it at the MySQL prompt to see what it returns. Without specifying the fields e.g.

```
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES (4, 5, 6)
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO FOO (X, Y, Z) VALUES (4, 5, 6)
```

will insert values in the order they are defined in the table (as shown using the `DESCRIBE` command) but is generally not a good idea in case for example the layout of the table changes.

You need to ensure that all your strings have opening and closing quotes - your `566789` string doesn't in the example you have given. Also you are passing what appear to be integers as strings. If they are defined as integers in the table you will need to remove the quotes.

Hope this helps.